# Recall arbitrary positional argument

Tags: macros, arguments

I'm trying to recall an argument based on another, i.e.

```
\newcommand{\switchtwo}[3]{#(#3)}
```

should return #1 if the third argument is 1 and #2 if the third argument is 2. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What shall happen in cases where the third argument neither is 1 nor is 2?

Comment: Do you want a check for digit-token `1`/`2`  or do you want a check for a number. E.g. Shall `\switchto{First}{Second}{2}` yield the same as `\newcounter{foobar}\setcounter{foobar}{2}`...`\switchto{First}{Second}{\number\value{foobar}}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\ifcase`:

```latex
\newcommand{\switchtwo}[3]{%
  \ifcase#3 \or#1\or#2\fi
}
```

The macro will return nothing if the third argument is neither 1 nor 2, but you'll get errors or garbage if the third argument is not an integer.

Your idea can't work, because the positional arguments in a definition are stored in a special way and you can't mix the replacement text with them.

Answer (score 4):

You can build an internal command of the right form

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\switchtwo#1#2#3{%
\def\tmp##1##2{###3}%
\tmp{#1}{#2}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\switchtwo{aaa}{bbb}{1}

\switchtwo{\string\or}{\string\fi}{2}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`\newcommand{\switchtwo}[3]{#(#3)}`— The syntax you have in mind implies the possibility of using `#⟨whatsoever⟩` for "dynamically" denoting arguments of a macro at times when that macro is expanded.

This is not possible in (La)TeX:

**Only at the time of defining a macro you can use `#1` and `#2` etc for denoting its parameters.**

**Denoting one of its arguments by `#⟨whatsoever⟩` at the time of expanding is not possible.**

At the time of expanding, the `⟨parameter-text⟩` of a macro's definition is taken for a set of directives for one by one gathering **arguments** from the token-stream:
When expansion of `\switchto` takes place, LaTeX gathers the arguments from the token-stream: First it gathers from the token-stream that argument/that set of tokens that is denoted by the definition-text's parameter `#1`. Then it gathers from the token-stream that argument/that set of tokens that is denoted by the definition-text's parameter `#2`.  Then it gathers from the token-stream that argument/that set of tokens that is denoted by the definition-text's parameter `#3`. Then it inserts these sets of tokens into the replacement-text which it returns to the token-stream.

What can you do in LaTeX?

David Carlisle showed [in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521449/118714) how to use  `##⟨whatsoever⟩` within the definition-text of a macro **for "dynamically denoting" one of the arguments of *another* macro, a temporary macro, at the time of *defining* that other/temporary macro.**

Approaches focused at defining temporary macros cannot be used in expansion-contexts.

Other possibilities (that can be used in expansion-contexts as well) are:

As long as it is ensured that the third argument is a `⟨number⟩` in the sense of The TeXbook—the precise meaning of the quantity `⟨number⟩` is discussed in The TeXbook, Chapter 24: Summary of vertical mode —, you can probably do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\switchtwo}[3]{%
  \romannumeral0\ifnum\number\number0#3=1 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\expandafter\@firstoftwo\@secondoftwo}{%
    \ifnum\number\number0#3=2 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\expandafter\@secondoftwo\@secondoftwo}%
    {\@firstoftwo}%
  }%
  { Error: Arg 3 is neither 1 nor 2}{{ #1}{ #2}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\switchtwo{A}{B}{1}

\switchtwo{A}{B}{2}

\switchtwo{A}{B}{3}

\switchtwo{A}{B}{}

\hrulefill

\newcounter{foobar}

\setcounter{foobar}{1}%
\switchtwo{A}{B}{\number\value{foobar}}

\setcounter{foobar}{2}%
\switchtwo{A}{B}{\number\value{foobar}}

\setcounter{foobar}{3}%
\switchtwo{A}{B}{\number\value{foobar}}

\end{document}
```

In the example above `\romannumeral0...` is not used for obtaining the roman-numeral-representation of a number. `\romannumeral0...` is used for triggering a lot of expansion-work during the search for more digits or a space-token that will be discarded as it just terminates the digit-sequence and therefore also terminates the search for more digits. It is ensured that after all this expansion-work a space-token is found, which terminates the digit-sequence `0`. Therefore after all the expansion-work a non-positive number is found while `\romannumeral` will silently swallow non-positive numbers without returning any tokens at all.

Be aware that a reliable test whether an arbitrary token sequence in `\switchtwo`'s third argument forms a valid `⟨number⟩` in the sense of The TeXbook is not feasible:

An arbitrary token sequence might form an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm. Therefore such a test includes testing whether the result of an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm forms a valid `⟨number⟩` in the sense of The TeXbook. This in turn implies testing whether an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm terminates at all (without error-messages). [This in turn implies solving the halting problem. Alan Mathison Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for all possible program-input pairs does not exist.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

---

In case you prefer checking whether the set of tokens contained in `\switchto`'s third argument (without whatsoever expansion/evaluation) consists either exactly of the catcode-12-(other)-character-token `1` or exactly of the catcode-12-(other)-character-token `2` or of something else, this can be done by means of delimited arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@DigitFork{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%              {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                which is to be checked is formed by a set of 
%%                tokens which contains only the catcode-12-character 1>}%
%%              {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                which is to be checked is formed by a set of 
%%                tokens which contains only the catcode-12-character 2>}%
%%              {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                which is to be checked is formed by a set of 
%%                tokens which is empty or contains something else>}%
%%
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToExclam{\long\def\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@DigitSelect{\long\def\UD@DigitSelect#1!!1!2!#2#3!!!!{#2}}%
\newcommand\UD@DigitFork[4]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!}{%
    \UD@DigitSelect
    !#1!1!2!{#4}% empty
    !!#1!2!{#2}% 1
    !!1!#1!{#3}% 2
    !!1!2!{#4}% something else without !
    !!!!%
  }{#4}% something else with !
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \switchto
\newcommand\switchtwo[3]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@DigitFork{#3}{ #1}{ #2}{ Error: Arg 3 is neither 1 nor 2}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\switchtwo{A}{B}{1}

\switchtwo{A}{B}{2}

\switchtwo{A}{B}{3}

\switchtwo{A}{B}{}

\hrulefill

Be aware that this variant of \verb|\switchto| does not evaluate its third argument
and that the token-set \verb|\number\value{foobar}| in any case neither does
equal the token \texttt{1$_{12}$} nor does equal the token \texttt{2$_{12}$}:

\newcounter{foobar}

\setcounter{foobar}{1}%
\switchtwo{A}{B}{\number\value{foobar}}

\setcounter{foobar}{2}%
\switchtwo{A}{B}{\number\value{foobar}}

\setcounter{foobar}{3}%
\switchtwo{A}{B}{\number\value{foobar}}

\end{document}
```

By the way:

None of the tests presented in this answer defines temporary macros.

Therefore the tests presented in this answer are suitable for expansion-contexts also.

E.g., you can do things like `\csname @\switchtwo{first}{second}{1}oftwo\endcsname{first}{second}`.

With the tests presented in this answer, the placement of the first and second argument of `\switchtwo` is done in a way where unbalanced `\csname`/`\endcsname`/`\if...`/`\or`/`\else`/`\fi` in the arguments don't disturb.

E.g., you can do things like `\csname @\switchtwo{\ifx AA}{\ifx AB}{1}first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname{first}{second}`.

But be aware that brace/group-nesting is independent from `\if..`..`\else`..`\fi`-matching and that therefore such things can disturb the `\if..`..`\else`..`\fi`-matching of surrounding `\if..`..`\else`..`\fi`-constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about selecting some arguments.

The question can be considered a special case of the question of selecting the K<sup>th</sup> argument from L consecutive non-delimited arguments.

In case you are interested in that, I can offer an expandable routine `\KeepKthOfLArguments` which lets you do that.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Layout of this example:
%%=============================================================================
\pagestyle{plain}%
\@ifundefined{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\@ifundefined{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\@ifundefined{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\@ifundefined{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\oddsidemargin=1.5cm
\topmargin=\oddsidemargin
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\advance\textwidth-2\oddsidemargin
\marginparsep=.375cm
\marginparwidth=\oddsidemargin
\advance\marginparwidth-2\marginparsep
\advance\oddsidemargin-1in
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\headheight=0ex
\headsep=0ex
\textheight=\paperheight
\advance\textheight-2\topmargin
\footskip=.5\topmargin
\advance\footskip.5\ht\strutbox
\advance\topmargin-1in
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother

\makeatletter
%% Code for \KeepKthOfLArguments: 
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@CheckWhetherNull
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Keep only the K-th of L consecutive undelimited arguments.
%%   ( IF K < 1 OR K > L just remove L consecutive undelimited arguments. )
%%=============================================================================
%% \KeepKthOfLArguments{<integer number K>}%
%%                     {<integer number L>}%
%%                     <sequence of L consecutive undelimited arguments>
%%
%% If L < 1 yields nothing.
%% Else:
%%   If K >= 1 and K < L  yields:
%%     <K-th undelimited argument from <sequence of L consecutive undelimited 
%%      arguments>>
%%   If K < 1 or K > L
%%     (-> there is no K-th argument in the
%%         <sequence of L consecutive undelimited arguments> )
%%   yields nothing  but removal of <sequence of L consecutive 
%%          undelimited arguments>
\newcommand\KeepKthOfLArguments[2]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  % #1: <integer number K>
  % #2: <integer number L>
  \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsKSmallerOneFork
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000\expandafter}%
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#2 000}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsKSmallerOneFork[2]{%
  % #1: <K letters m>
  % #2: <L letters m >
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{% K is smaller than one:
    \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#2}{ }{}%
  }{% K is not smaller than one:
    \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
    \expandafter{%
      \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
    }{%
      \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop{#1}{#2}%
    }{#2}%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop[4]{%
  % #1: <K letters m>  
  % #2: <L letters m>
  % (For detecting whether K>L or K<=L, during the loop letters m will
  %  be removed both from #1 and #2 until at least one of these arguments 
  %  is empty.
  %  When the loop terminates with 0<K<=L, #1 will be empty and #2
  %  will hold an amount of letters m corresponding to the the 
  %  difference L-K.
  %  When the loop terminates with K>L, #1 will not be empty and #2
  %  will be empty.
  % )
  % #3: <K-1 letters m>
  % #4: <L letters m>
  % (#3 and #4 will be left untouched during the loop so they can be 
  %  used for performing appropriate action when loop terminates as
  %  it is known whether K>L.)
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{% We have K<=L:
     \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{%
       #3%
      }{%
       \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#2}{ }%
      }{}%
  }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{% We have K>L:
      \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#4}{ }{}%
    }{% We don't know yet whether K<=L or K>L, thus remove letters m and 
      % do another iteration:
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
      \expandafter{%
        \UD@firstoftwo{}#2%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop
        \expandafter{%
          \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
        }%
      }{#3}{#4}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{<N letters m>}%
%%                                        {<argument 1>}%
%%                                        {<argument 2>}%
%%                                        <sequence of consecutive 
%%                                         undelimited arguments>
%%.............................................................................
%% Removes the first N undelimited arguments from the <sequence of 
%% consecutive undelimited arguments>, then inserts  
%% <argument 1><argument 2>
%%
%% On the one hand when providing <argument 2> empty, you can use 
%% <argument 1> for nesting calls to \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments.
%% On the other hand you can provide a <space token> for stopping
%% \romannumeral-expansion as  <argument 1> and have the
%% macro grab the <K-th undelimited argument> from the <sequence of L 
%% consecutive undelimited arguments> as <argument 2>.
%%
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments[3]{%
  %% #1: <N letters m>  
  %% #2: <Argument 1>   
  %% #3: <Argument 2>
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{#2#3}{%
    \UD@firstoftwo{%
      \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments
      \expandafter{%
        \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
      }{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% End of code for \KeepKthOfLArguments.
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\footnotesize

\noindent\texttt{%
  \string\KeepKthOfLArguments\allowbreak\{1\}\allowbreak\{30\}\allowbreak\{Word 1\}\allowbreak\{Word 2\}%
  \allowbreak\{Word 3\}\allowbreak\{Word 4\}\allowbreak\{Word 5\}\allowbreak\{Word 6\}\allowbreak\{Word 7\}%
  \allowbreak\{Word 8\}\allowbreak\{Word 9\}\allowbreak\{Word 10\}\allowbreak\{Word 11\}\allowbreak\{Word 12\}%
  \allowbreak\{Word 13\}\allowbreak\{Word 14\}\allowbreak\{Word 15\}\allowbreak\{Word 16\}\allowbreak\{Word 17\}%
  \allowbreak\{Word 18\}\allowbreak\{Word 19\}\allowbreak\{Word 20\}\allowbreak\{Word 21\}\allowbreak\{Word 22\}%
  \allowbreak\{Word 23\}\allowbreak\{Word 24\}\allowbreak\{Word 25\}\allowbreak\{Word 26\}\allowbreak\{Word 27\}%
  \allowbreak\{Word 28\}\allowbreak\{Word 29\}\allowbreak\{Word 30\}%
} yields:
\KeepKthOfLArguments{1}{30}{Word 1}{Word 2}{Word 3}{Word 4}{Word 5}{Word 6}%
                           {Word 7}{Word 8}{Word 9}{Word 10}{Word 11}{Word 12}%
                           {Word 13}{Word 14}{Word 15}{Word 16}{Word 17}{Word 18}%
                           {Word 19}{Word 20}{Word 21}{Word 22}{Word 23}{Word 24}%
                           {Word 25}{Word 26}{Word 27}{Word 28}{Word 29}{Word 30}%

\newcount\loopcnt
\loopcnt=2 %
\loop
  \vskip\partopsep\vskip\topsep
  \noindent\texttt{%
    \string\KeepKthOfLArguments\allowbreak\{\number\loopcnt\}\allowbreak\{30\}\allowbreak\{Word 1\}\allowbreak\{Word 2\}%
    \allowbreak\{Word 3\}\allowbreak\{Word 4\}\allowbreak\{Word 5\}\allowbreak\{Word 6\}\allowbreak\{Word 7\}%
    \allowbreak\{Word 8\}\allowbreak\{Word 9\}\allowbreak\{Word 10\}\allowbreak\{Word 11\}\allowbreak\{Word 12\}%
    \allowbreak\{Word 13\}\allowbreak\{Word 14\}\allowbreak\{Word 15\}\allowbreak\{Word 16\}\allowbreak\{Word 17\}%
    \allowbreak\{Word 18\}\allowbreak\{Word 19\}\allowbreak\{Word 20\}\allowbreak\{Word 21\}\allowbreak\{Word 22\}%
    \allowbreak\{Word 23\}\allowbreak\{Word 24\}\allowbreak\{Word 25\}\allowbreak\{Word 26\}\allowbreak\{Word 27\}%
    \allowbreak\{Word 28\}\allowbreak\{Word 29\}\allowbreak\{Word 30\}%
  } yields:
  \KeepKthOfLArguments{\number\loopcnt}{30}{Word 1}{Word 2}{Word 3}{Word 4}{Word 5}{Word 6}%
                             {Word 7}{Word 8}{Word 9}{Word 10}{Word 11}{Word 12}%
                             {Word 13}{Word 14}{Word 15}{Word 16}{Word 17}{Word 18}%
                             {Word 19}{Word 20}{Word 21}{Word 22}{Word 23}{Word 24}%
                             {Word 25}{Word 26}{Word 27}{Word 28}{Word 29}{Word 30}%
  \par
\ifnum\loopcnt<30 \advance\loopcnt by 1 %
\repeat

\vskip\partopsep\vskip\topsep
\noindent\verb|\KeepKthOfLArguments| does deliver the result after two
expansion-steps:

\begin{verbatim}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \KeepKthOfLArguments{3}{11}{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}%
}%
\end{verbatim}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \KeepKthOfLArguments{3}{11}{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}%
}%
\noindent\texttt{\string\test: \meaning\test}%

\end{document}
```

Using the routine `\KeepKthOfLArguments` you could define `\switchtwo` as follows:

```
\newcommand\switchtwo[3]{\KeepKthOfLArguments{#3}{2}{#1}{#2}}%
```

[image]

[image]